# MongoDB + Express: How to verify login credentials using db.collection().findOne() or .find()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, database

I have a POST request with a user credentials as an object from a Login page and gets passed to the API Server like so:

```
  loginUser(creds) {
    //creds is in the form of { username: bob, password: 123 }

    var request = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(creds),
    }

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/login`, request)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user);
      console.log('Successful')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error is', err)
    })
  },
```

And API Server receives it like so:

```
//With .findOne()
    app.post('/api/login/', function(req, res) {
      console.log('Req body in login ', req.body)
      db.collection('users').findOne(req.body, function(err, isMatch) {
        console.log('ISMATCH IS: ' + isMatch)
        if(err) {
          console.log('THIS IS ERROR RESPONSE')
          res.json(err)
        } else {
          console.log('THIS IS ISMATCH RESPONSE')
          res.json(isMatch)
        }
      })
    })
```

or

```
//With .find()
    app.post('/api/login/', function(req, res) {
      console.log('Req body in login ', req.body)
      //console logs correctly as { username: bob, password: 123 }
      db.collection('users').find(req.body).next(function(err, isMatch) {
        console.log('ISMATCH IS: ' + isMatch)
        if(err) {
          console.log('THIS IS ERROR RESPONSE')
          res.json(err)
        } else {
          console.log('THIS IS ISMATCH RESPONSE')
          res.json(isMatch)
        }
      })
    })
```

So with the login credentials passed in, inside the API server, I would like to search my `'users'` database to see if any matches the one being passed in. But in both cases, `isMatch` is always `null` and always logs `console.log('THIS IS ISMATCH RESPONSE')` even if the user credentials do not match any in the database. And on the client-side, I never get any error responses and always logs `console.log('Successful')`.

Can't seem to figure out what I am missing. What could I be doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to find the user first and then compare the password, something like:

```
db.collection('users').findOne({ username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {
        console.log('User found ');
        // In case the user not found   
        if(err) {
          console.log('THIS IS ERROR RESPONSE')
          res.json(err)
        } 
        if (user && user.password === req.body.password){
          console.log('User and password is correct')
          res.json(user);
        } else {
          console.log("Credentials wrong");
          res.json({data: "Login invalid"});
        }              
 });
```

Comment: It works fine. :) But it doesn't seem to be the suggested way as it compares the credentials with code, rather than Database server itself.

Comment: Thank you @NaveenKumarV, I think your answer complement mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [$and Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) in the [.findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) method.

**Working example:**

```
db.collection('users').findOne( 

    { $and: [ 
      { name: req.body.username.toLowerCase() }, 
      { password: req.body.password } 
    ] }, 

   (err, result) => {

    if(err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
      return;
    }

    if(!result) {
        data = {
            "meta": {
                "status": "fail",
                "message": "Login Failure: Invalid username or password"
            }
        };
        res.status(401).send(data);
    } else {
        data = {
            "meta": {
                "status": "success",
                "message": "Login success"
            }
        };
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```